# Searching a text file for a line of text matching the text inputted from a user Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, search

When the user enters a phrase, key words out of the phrase needs to be matched to text in a text file and then the line out of the text file can be printed back to the user.

e.g. when a user types in "my phone screen is blank" or "the display screen is blank" there should be the same solution outputted to the screen from the text file.

```
searchfile = open("phone.txt", "r")

question = input (" Welcome to the phone help center, What is the problem?")
  if question in ["screen", "display", "blank"]:
        for line in searchfile:
            if question in line:
                print (line)


elif question in ["battery", "charged", "charging", "switched", "off"]:
        for line in searchfile:
            if question in line:
                print (line)

            else:
                if question in ["signal", "wifi", "connection"]:
                    for line in searchfile:
                        if question in line:
                                print (line)

searchfile.close()
```

inside the text file:

Screen: Your screen needs to be replaced Battery: your battery needs to be charged signal: you do not have a signal

Comment: can you share phone.txt file.? if not confidential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First these 2 lines do not work as per your requirement:

```
question = raw_input(" Welcome to the phone help center, What is the problem?")
if question in ["screen", "display", "blank"]:
```

If user types *my phone screen is blank*, as the full sentence is not member of the list, the remaining of the if will not be executed. You should instead test whether any member of the list exists in the sentence:

```
question = raw_input(" Welcome to the phone help center, What is the problem?")
for k in  ["screen", "display", "blank"]:
    if k in question:
        for line in searchfile:
            if k in line:             # or maybe  if 'screen' in line ?
                print line
                break
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

Here is the working code:

```
search_file = open(r"D:\phone.txt", "r")

question = raw_input(" Welcome to the phone help center, What is the problem?")
if question in ["screen", "display", "blank"]:
    for line in search_file:
        if question in line:
            print (line)


elif question in ["battery", "charged", "charging", "switched", "off"]:
        for line in search_file:
            if question in line:
                print (line)
else:
    if question in ["signal", "wifi", "connection"]:
        for line in search_file:
            if question in line:
                print (line)

search_file.close()
```